# On Refresh or On Load Page - AngularJS Code is shown

Tags: angularjs

I am new in AngularJS.

I am fetching data from the Rest API and displaying it on the page.

My Supposed code is giving below.

```
$http.get(local_url+'/data').
    then(function(response) {
        $scope.data = response.data.client_data;
    });
```

Now when suppose I write.

```
<p>{{ data.name }}</p>
```

So when i come on page, it is showing above `{{ data.name }}` code after sometime it is showing any name.

=============================================================

Solution.

I used in body tag like that. `<body ng-cloak>` It will work.

thanks.

Comment: use `ng-cloak` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak or define the `$scope.data = ""` as empty string before the `$http` method.

Comment: that's because the http request is asynchronous so as soon as the API responds the data wil be binded to the scope variable. try to initialise the $scope.data with a value of your choice.

Comment: I need to use <p ng-cloak>{{ data.name }}</p> Like that ??

Comment: hope this will help http://plnkr.co/edit/6TgBU6uJw3On5hifpyGm?p=preview

Comment: Thanks man @Red.

Comment: Yes you can use `<p ng-cloak>{{data.name}}</p>`. Did this work for you? If so, i create an awnser of it. This might help future users solve their problem.

Comment: Thanks @Red. I have resolved issue.

Comment: If you like then post your answer for future users.

Comment: Ok created an awnser, provided some more information. Hopefully its more helpfull for you and future users. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is define the `$scope.data` before the `$http` as an empty string

```
$scope.data = "";
```

You also could use the build in `ngCloak` directive. This will prevent `AngularJS` from displaying the `$scope` in its raw form.

You can find more info about it inside the `AngularJS` docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

Another option would be to use the `ng-if` or `ng-show` expression, to check whether a value isset or not before rendering the `element`.

```
<p ng-if="data.name">{{data.name}}</p>
```

or

```
<p ng-show="data.name">{{data.name}}</p>
```

Where `ng-if` clones the element and `appends` it to the document when the expression is `true` and `ng-show` just toggles a `display: none;` or `display: block;` state on the element.

**Helpfull Links:**
[ng-if documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)
[ng-show documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)